# Cannot display posts on page except for index

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Here is what I'm trying to do: I am trying to display all the excerpts of my posts to my `blog.php` page but it does not display the posts in the `blog.php` page, it only works in the `index.php` page. Let me explain more.....

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'excerpt', get_post_format() );

  endwhile;
?>
```

If I put that in the `index.php`, it will show the excerpt of the posts. I also have a page called `blog.php`. I have changed the page template to the `blog.php` file. But when I put the same code in the `blog.php` page from above, it only displays the page content but not all the posts. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Well in short, if you haven't defined a WP_Query for the blog.php page or assigned a certain number of posts to it in your WP Admin, then you will only get the one post that was created by the WP_Query that created "The Loop".

To understand this better, take a look at:

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/the-wordpress-loop-explained-for-beginners

and

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

Answer (score 0):

ok.....i got it to work with this code:

```
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // get current page number
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'), // the value from Settings > Reading by default
    'paged'          => $current_page // current page
);
query_posts( $args );

$wp_query->is_archive = true;
$wp_query->is_home = false;

while(have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>
    <h2><?php the_title() /* post title */ ?></h2>
    <p><?php the_content() /* post content */ ?></p>
    <?php
endwhile;
```

https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/separate-blog-pages.html